# Using Proc with ruby hash merge results in

Tags: ruby, proc

I'm trying to DRY up my code by using Procs. I have many lines that look like this (other lines may have fees, discounts, taxes, rather than revenue):

```
h.merge!({revenue: 500}){|key, old_val, new_val| old_val + new_val}
```

I tried to write a Proc that looks like this:

```
hproc = Proc.new {|key, old_val, new_val| old_val + new_val}
```

And simplify the first line by doing this:

```
h.merge!({revenue: 500})(&hproc)
```

However, I get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting end-of-input
h.merge!({revenue:600})(&hproc)
                    ^
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: By the way, it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: You answered it sawa! Thank you, it turned out to be a syntax error as you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

```
h.merge!({revenue: 500}, &hproc)
```