# Passing block to select through send method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
my_array = [[1, 'foo_parent', nil], [2,'bar_is_son_of_foo', 1], [3, 'zok_is_son_of_bar', 2]]

def children_block
  Proc.new do |c|  
    if c.is_a? Array
      c[2] == self[0] 
    end
  end
end

my_array.send(:select) &children_block
```

gives me ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4)

Comment: There is no method `third` on array, only `first` and `last`, also don't think `self.first` makes sense in `Proc`

Comment: [14] pry(main)> array = [1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                                              
=> [1, 2, 3]
[15] pry(main)> array.third                                                                                                                                                                    
=> 3

Comment: Where does your error point to?

Comment: Okay, `third` is not part of core ruby, may be rails or something else is adding it

Comment: @WandMaker yup, active_support adds up to `.fifth` and `forty_two` if I remember correctly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa - OP wants to find those arrays whose first element is same as last element of another array - note input is array of arrays.  If one looks at the array of arrays, it starts making sense

Comment: [11] pry(main)> my_array.send(:select, &children_block)                                                                                                                              
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..4)
from (pry):11:in `select'

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to pass a block to `select` via `send`.

```
my_array.send(:select, &children_block)
```

Here is a working sample:

```
my_array = [[1, 'foo_parent', nil], [2,'bar_is_son_of_foo', 1], [3, 'zok_is_son_of_bar', 2]]

def children_block
  Proc.new do |c|  
    p c
  end
end

p my_array.send(:select, &children_block)
#=> [1, "foo_parent", nil]
    [2, "bar_is_son_of_foo", 1]
    [3, "zok_is_son_of_bar", 2]
```

The problem you are trying to solve can be also solved using:

```
my_array.select {|i| my_array.find {|j| j.first == i.last} }
```

or

```
my_array.select {|i| my_array.find {|j| i.first == j.last} }
```

depending on which elements you are interested in.

<sup>PS: [There was another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386308/using-proc-with-ruby-hash-merge-results-in) today with similar issue with respect to passing block.  First part of my answer is derivation of that question's answer</sup>

Comment: [3] pry(main)> test.send(:select, &children_block)                                                                                           still gives me an error                                                  
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)

Comment: I have shared a minimal working code, you can check that.  I am not sure what is `test` that you are using.

Comment: Sorry Wand. Please consider "my_array" instead of test, I was copying from my console.

Comment: The problem that you are showing is not from this piece of code, the issue is somewhere else.  Update your question with full stack trace if you have that

Answer (score 0):

Blocks and lambdas/procs aren't the same, you can't just replace one with the other. The following should guide you in the right direction

```
my_array.send(:select) { |element| filter_somehow(element) }
```

Comment: But you can use lambda/proc as a block.